# Dropdown primeng 15.4.1 not work after update selected on subscribe in Angular15

Tags: angular

I have p-dropdown element,
i change the selected on subscribe, the selected is not updated.
I see on 'subscribe' the selected is update.

`<p-dropdown [options]="primecities" [(ngModel)]="selectedCity" optionLabel="Name"></p-dropdown>` 
this.apiService.getData(url).subscribe({
next: (res) => {

```
            this.primecities = [
                {Id:"1", Name: 'New York', Guid:"12"},
                {Id:"11", Name: 'XXX',  Guid:"12"},
                {Id:"21", Name: 'VVVV', Guid:"12"},
                {Id:"31", Name: 'GGGG',Guid:"12"},
                {Id:"41", Name: 'RRRRR',Guid:"12"},
            ];
            this.selectedCity=this.primecities[2]

}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to:

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedCity"
```

This should make sure it updates the value as you pick a different entry.
Source: https://primeng.org/dropdown#group

If you want to make sure that the value get's preset you need to make sure the values get's set before the dropdown get's rendered.
Have a look here for that:
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work :( I updated the question